# How to hang an event on an element that appears in the DOM later?

Tags: javascript, events, browserify, buttonclick

I use Browserify to work with modules (require) in JS. But when I render an element in a js file and want to hang an event on it(onclick), the following error appears

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined`

How to hang an event on an element that appears in the DOM later?

Comment: You could provide an actual code example, this could help others to find a solution to your problem.

Comment: You can't although since events bubble by default (unless something in between did `event.stopPropagation()`) you can put the click handler on an element higher up in the chain and inspect `event.target`. Sounds like you need to rethink what you're doing though or allow a UI framework to guide you on to better practices.

Answer (score 0):

> How to hang an event on an element that appears in the DOM later?

No way to do this. Your should change logic of you application. Your can listening onClick event on parent. And then select element's to choose the new one your need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) for that. Basically you add an event listener to `document`. In the handler method you check the event `target` for a distinguishing property. If the `target` contains the property, do something, if not, nothing happens. This way, later added elements can be handled.

```js
// add a listener to document
document.addEventListener("click", showClick);

// ad a new element to the DOM
const newElement = document.createElement("div");
newElement.innerHTML = "I am new! Click me!";
newElement.id = "new";
newElement.style.cursor = "pointer";
document.body.appendChild(newElement);

// this handles all clicks
function showClick(evt) {
  // if it's div#new, do something
  if (evt.target.id === "new") {
    console.log("there we are!");
  }
  // otherwise nothing happens
}
```

```html
<div id="notnew">I exist after page load. Try clicking me, I dare you!</div>
```